# Flow for Redux Actions - Property not found in object type

Tags: redux, flowtype

In type checking reducers with Flow, when my actions return either:

```
{ type: TYPE_1 }
```

or

```
{ type: TYPE_2, data: { key: value } }
```

How can I avoid "Property not found in object literal" when attempting to union the two actions:

```
type Action = { type: string } | { type: string, data: Object };
```

Comment: Why are you saying the type is `string` in your declarations? If it has a specific type string, you should be doing `type: "TYPE_1"` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing is to be more specific which actions can happen like so:

```js
type Action1 = { type: 'TYPE_1' };
type Action2 = { type: 'TYPE_2', data: Object };

type Action =
  | Action1
  | Action2;
```

I would also specify the type of the `data` a bit more **if** that matters inside of the reducer.

ref: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/#toc-typing-redux-actions

Comment: I am actually still getting the error: "property (data) is not found in object type (action)"

Comment: @JeffWeinberg Can you provide a http://flow.org/try link please? I'll try to have a look then 